# how to have a defaultdict or dictionary with a fixed list or array size as the value

Tags: python

I was trying to use d = defaultdict(array.array) or d = defaultdict(list) for the dictionary, but I dont't know how I can fix the number of elements in the array.array or list to N where N is the size of the array I always want the list or array.array to be. If possible I want all of the N elements of the list to be pre-initialized to zero.

Answer (score 9):

The argument to `defaultdict()` is a callable that creates the default value, so just create a function that creates your starting value:

```
N = 8  # change N to whatever you want
def default_list():
    return [0] * N

d = defaultdict(default_list)
```

Or as a lambda:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * N)
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass `defaultdict` a function which returns a value, so just give it a function that returns a list or array of the appropriate size. For example:

```
def make_list_of_10_zeroes():
    return [0] * 10

d = defaultdict(make_list_of_10_zeroes)
```

Since the function we're using here has only one statement which is a `return`, we can use [a lambda](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) instead:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * 10)
```